# React - can't stream video from webcam

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, webcam

I'm trying to fix my Component to streaming data from webcam. It renders successfully and successfully gets access to webcam. But I have no idea why video tag do not plays anything. How to fix this? What am I missing?

```
export class WebcamStream extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            src: null
        }
        this.videoRef = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // getting access to webcam
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({video: true})
            .then(stream => this.setState({src: stream}))
            .catch(console.log);
    }

    render() {
        return <video id={this.props.id}
                      ref={() => this.videoRef.srcObject = this.state.src}
                      width={this.props.width}
                      height={this.props.height}
                      autoPlay="autoplay"
                      title={this.props.title}></video>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I have found what was wrong. According to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) I need to use `current` property to make the node accessible. So, the full working example of my Webcam component:

```
export class WebcamStream extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.videoTag = React.createRef()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // getting access to webcam
       navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({video: true})
            .then(stream => this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream)
            .catch(console.log);
    }

    render() {
        return <video id={this.props.id}
                      ref={this.videoTag}
                      width={this.props.width}
                      height={this.props.height}
                      autoPlay
                      title={this.props.title}></video>
    }
}
```

`this.setState` was removed in prior of direct `srcObject` changing from promise, but I'm not sure if this React way. Maybe, more correctly is moving `this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream` code as setState callback?

Comment: It looks clean enough to say it is react way. If you are using the set-state to store the src, you may use the `src` prop of the video tag directly without ref callback. Another solution is to render the video tag on demand after the src is already available. Render null if src is not available, and then render video if src is available.

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` is not correctly used in this line:

```
ref={() => this.videoRef.srcObject = this.state.src}
```

As in your code just sets the `src` to the `videoRef` which is not initialized so it never gets to the video tag.

You may try:

```
ref={this.videoRef.srcObject}
```

And in the componentDidMount:

```
.then(stream => {this.videoRef.srcObject = stream})
```

Or simply:

```
ref={(e) => e.srcObject = this.state.src}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to update my `render()` method according to your example, but when I changed `ref` to `ref={(e) => e.srcObject = this.state.src}` I got next error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'srcObject' of null`

Comment: btw, `ref={(e) => e.srcObject = this.state.src}` harms performance, because each re-render new funcion creates

Comment: Well to be fair, if you are loading a video which already uses tons of resources, and you also not going to re-render the component many times... the creation of the function is the latest one to care optimization for.

Answer (score 1):

The component that worked for me is the following

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ModalVideo(props) { 
    const [video,]=useState(React.createRef());

    const videoError=(error)=>{
        console.log("error",error);
    }

    const handleVideo=(stream)=>{
        video.current.srcObject = stream;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <video ref={video}  autoPlay={true} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing same error when using same above code it is showing " _this2.video is undefined; can't access its "current" property" and All things is right , take vedio permission but it is not showing vedio in my page.